# How to set inherited parameters of deserialized class via GSON?

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have these two classes :

```
  abstract class Parent(val parent_parameter:Int)
  class Child(val child_parameter:Int):Parent(child_parameter)
```

And I want to deserialize this json with GSON :

```
 {
     "child_parameter":1
 }
```

Here's the deszerialization via Gson

```
 val child = GsonBuilder()
                .create()
                .fromJson(json,Child::class.java)
```

As the parent_parameter is initialized with the child_parameter I was planing to get parent_parameter = 1. But it's not the case. Gson seems to don't initialized the parent parameters.

Any thoughts on how I can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your JSON input as well.

Comment: this actually just the one I've posted